# Hooking up two voltage regulators for more power?

Tags: led, current-source

I have two LM317's, which I am wiring up as a current source for two high power, 10 watt LED's.

[image]

The 317 can operate @ 1.5 amps maximum, so I plan to build two of these circuits.

The problem I am running across is the output pin has continuity with the metal casing, and I wanted to use one heat sink. The metal casing touches the screw, so there is no way I can put an insulator in between, the screw will still make it short.

So can I have both output pins touching, and run everything together, assuming each LED takes the same amount of current?

Comment: I am no expert but voltage regulators in parallel doesn't seem like a good idea - there is no guarantee they will share the load equally.

Comment: That's what mica pads, heat transfer compound, and Teflon screws are for.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Or one of those plastic insulation rivets that almost always are included in insulated TO220 mounting sets :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give an official answer:

No, it's not okay. With today's production you can give it a try in a small experiment, in the hopes the margins on the internals are small enough to make the share go between 40/60 and 60/40, but for long term or unmonitored use: No! Too many risks.

See @IgnacioVazques-Abrams' comment about insulation materials used to mount TO220 packages with sufficient insulation.

Apart from that, the same risks apply to the LEDs, unless you add balancing resistors there as well. Supposedly this is okay, as you are using linear current control, so 'wasting' another half volt in an extra resistor won't be hurting too much.

To give the full explanation, let's assume one LM317 has a 1.215 reference and the other has a 1.225 reference. If you then add them together at the adjust and output points one device wants to put Vadj+1.225 on the top of the resistor, the other Vadj+1.215. This starts out with them competing a little and then slowly the balance most likely goes more and more to the higher voltage one, heating it more than the other, then the balance can get further out of whack, until the high valued one would have to insert 2.5A into the whole of it, which it will not for long, if at all.